# Calculating P(X>6|X<8) from pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a pdf $\frac{k}{x^2}$ for $4<x<\infty$ ($0$ otherwise) and need to work out the $P(X>6 | X<8)$ I already worked out *k* to equal 4.

To work out this probability I did $\frac{P(X>6)}{P(X<8)}$ but I get a weird answer/

For $P(X>6)$ i did $\int_{6}^{\infty} \frac{4}{x^2}dx = \frac{2}{3} $

and for $P(X<8)$ i did $\int_{4}^{8} \frac{4}{x^2}dx = \frac{1}{2} $

My answer of $\frac{3}{4} $ is obviously wrong, but I am not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: "To work out this probability I did $\frac{P(X>6)}{P(X<8)}$" This is odd, this ratio being unrelated to $P(X>6 | X<8)$. What is the **definition** of $P(X>6 | X<8)$, already?

Comment: what mean pdf ?

Comment: It wasn't sure, but all the examples in my study book used this method... but now I realise that all those examples were for a discrete pf.. but they don't discuss how to work it out with a continuous pdf?
I was not sure if this question different to working out $P(6<X<8)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compute \begin{align}\frac{P(6<X<8)}{P(X<8)}&=\frac{P(X<8)-P(X \le 6)}{P(X<8)}\\&=1-\frac{P(X \le 6)}{P(X < 8)}
\\&=1-\frac{1-P(X > 6)}{P(X < 8)}\\
 \end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$P(X>6 | X < 8) = \frac{P((6<X)\cap (X<8))}{P(X<8)} = \frac{P(6 < X<8)}{P(X<8)} = \frac{k\int_6^8\frac{dx}{x^2}}{k\int_4^8\frac{dx}{x^2}} = \frac{\int_6^8\frac{dx}{x^2}}{\int_4^8\frac{dx}{x^2}}$$

Note that the probability density function lives on $(4,\infty$). That's why the lower integral starts at 4.